# Magento status and state flow analyses

Tags: sql, status

we would like to do a Magento state and status flow analyses. In short: a count over all orders grouped by unique state and status flow.

```
new -> payment pending -> cancelled #3 
new -> payment pending -> payment complete -> completed #54
new -> awaiting payment #16
```

This does look as a very difficult query as the status and state is stored in the history table in separate rows. So one would have to capture the complete table. Then group by order and sort by date. Extract and print the order id, then the statuses based on sorted date + do a count over the number of orders using this path.

Hmmmm - writing this gives some ideas, but also seems quite complex

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to usa a seperate table where you have the order id and a status list field. Next you process all status changes and write that new status to the status list field (comma seperated). Now you can just do a group on the status list field and count the records of them.

Comment: Cool. I Will also try this backwards compatible with a query. Help and ideas appreciated.